# Logic for displaying infinite category tree in nested <ul>s from Self Join Table

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, nested, hierarchical-data

Please help me solve my big problem.
in my on-line shopping project i created a **dynamic Category List (with Infinite Level Depth)** Implemented in a Single Table in DB with Self join.
the schema is like below:
[image]
<sub>(source: [aspalliance.com](http://aspalliance.com/ArticleFiles/822/image002.gif))</sub>

**Update**
I want to use a JQuery plugin to make a Multi Level Menu bar. this plugin uses `<ul>` and `<li>` elements so I should transform the DB table to `<ul>` and `<li>`. the result should like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Clothing 1
    <ul>
      <li>Trousers 2
        <ul>
          <li>Mens trousers 3</li>
          <li>Ladies trousers 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li> 
      <li>Jackets 2</li>
      <li>Shirts 2</li>
      <li>Shoes
        <ul>
          <li>Mens shoes 3
            <ul>
              <li>Mens formal shoes 4</li>
              <li>Mens casual shoes 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Kids shoes 3</li>
          <li>Ladies shoes 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  <li>Cars 1
   <ul>
     <li>Small cars 2</i>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I can use a nested data control(like repeater control) but you know, with this solution i just can implement a list with non-infinite hierarchical tree structure.
**please help me! any suggestion?? I googled the web but not a suitable way found. I use *ASP.net 3.5 and LINQ*.**

what is the best way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this recursive method

```
private string GenerateUL(IQueryable<Menu> menus)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine("<ul>");
    foreach (var menu in menus)
    {
        if (menu.Menus.Any())
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<li>" + menu.Text);
            sb.Append(GenerateUL(menu.Menus.AsQueryable()));
            sb.AppendLine("</li>");
        }
        else
            sb.AppendLine("<li>" + menu.Text + "</li>");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</ul>");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

like this

```
DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var s = GenerateUL(context.Menus.Where(m => m.ParentID == null));
Response.Write(s);
```

Comment: how to apply this method if i pass dataset to the parameter of GenerateUL function? suppose that my dataset contains all the categories and sub categories in them. Their is column parent where we set the id of the parent. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think ASP.NET [`TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) is your friend.

Take a look [here](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx) too.

Also, you might want to use a dynamically created nested DataGrid or Repeater, here is an example (you can make it dynamic, so the nested (or even the parent) repeaters are genenerated programmatically.

```
void GenerateChildren(Menu menu)
{
    //Create DataGridRow/RepeaterRow/TreeViewNode/whatever for this menu
    menu.Children.Load();
    foreach (var child in menu.Children)
    {
        GenerateChildren(child);        
    }
}
```

**Update**
See example 5 on [this](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/menu/demo/demo.html) page.
I would recommend generating the jQuery code by server, so it's easier for you to control both the menus and the jQ generated menus.

Comment: can you explain more about your suggestion? I want to use a JQuery plugin to make a Multi Level Menu bar. this plugin uses <ul> and <li> elements so I should transform the DB table to <ul> and <li>!!!

Comment: I am not sure about jQuery, I haven't touch it for a long while, but if you have many sub item levels (more than 5) and it's a lot of data, consider using ajax to populate menus on demand.
Anyway, following examples might help you a lot, and create a js function in the jQuery that loops thru the menu tree and creates sub-menus.
http://www.devwebpro.com/jquery-navigation-menu-tutorials
HTH
http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/menu/demo/demo.html