# I need to have an idea for constructing menu management in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to have an idea for constructing menu management in asp.net,

I want to manage menus is like DotNetNuke Cms

Database tables is shown below

thanks

```
menuid   text       parentid    
64  product     null
65  wireless    64
66  sony            65
67  panasonic       65
68  camera      64
69  phone       64
70  sony        68
71  sony        65
```

Answer (score 0):

use the recursive method suggested by Alexander Prokofyev in this question

[Logic for displaying infinite category tree in nested <ul>s from Self Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485434/logic-for-displaying-infinite-category-tree-in-nested-uls-from-self-join-table)

this way your menu would be dynamic