# Generate Nested Menu from datatable using c# as ul list not Asp.net Menu control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-lists

I need to generate a custom menu which has submenu's using list ul from the `DataTable`

Below is the sample of Database and sample HTML ul list with dummy data.

```
PID         MENU                 Handler                  PageLangID  ParentID    IssueID     CatID       MenuPosition
----------- -------------------- ------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------

6           Business             Category.aspx    1           6           1           16          1
6           Culture              Category.aspx    1           6           1           3           1
6           Economy              Category.aspx    1           6           1           2           1
6           Finance              Category.aspx    1           6           1           19          1
6           Infrastructure       Category.aspx    1           6           1           17          1
6           Lifestyle            Category.aspx    1           6           1           20          1
6           Others               Category.aspx    1           6           1           21          1
6           People               Category.aspx    1           6           1           7           1
6           Politics             Category.aspx    1           6           1           1           1
6           Sports               Category.aspx    1           6           1           4           1
12          1002                  Default.aspx             1           12          3           1           1
12          1003                  Default.aspx             1           12          4           1           1
12          1006                  Default.aspx             1           12          1           1           1
12          1009                  Default.aspx             1           12          5           1           1
1           Home                 Default.aspx             1           0           1           1           10
11          Video                Videos.aspx              1           10          1           1           10
2           About Us             Page.aspx                1           0           1           1           20
5           Articles             Articles.aspx            1           0           1           1           20
6           Categories           Category.aspx    1           0
```

DESIRED HTML OUTPUT

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
<ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-linear"  >
    <li><span class="dir"><a href="./">Home</a></span></li>
    <li ><span class="dir"><a href="ultimate.linear.html">About Us</a></span>
        <ul >
            <li><a href="./">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Our Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">The Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Press</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">FAQs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="active" ><span class="dir"><a href="ultimate.linear-active.html">Categories</a></span>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Politics</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Economy</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Finance</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Group News</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Culture</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Lifestyle</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Sports</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Infrastructure</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Book Review</a></li>   
            <li><a href="./">Others</a></li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I don't want to use nested repeater controls. I would appreciate sample code which i can work with.

**UPDATED**: This code doesn't work, definitely i am doing something wrong

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
     DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

    //dt.Select("ParentID == 0") ;
    var s = GenerateUL(dt.Select("ParentID == 0"));
    Response.Write(s);

}


private string GenerateUL(var menus)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendLine("<ul>");
    foreach (var menu in menus)
    {
        if (menu.Menus.Any())
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<li>" + menu.Text);
            sb.Append(GenerateUL(menu.Menus.AsQueryable()));
            sb.AppendLine("</li>");
        }
        else
            sb.AppendLine("<li>" + menu.Text + "</li>");
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</ul>");

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**LATEST UPDATE BASED ON DANI SOLUTION**

It seems to work fine with his data sample but when i use it with my actual data it generate StackOverflowException was unhandled.

Below is the screen shot of the error.
[image]

Error is generated when it goes into sort of infinate loop where `PID=6` My actual data which is show above has 23 records & is result of UNION from different tabel that is the reason i have multiple rows in table where `PID=6` i am afraid it will also do same where `pid=12`.

Even if i catch the exception my website still crash due to this ...

**Latest CODE**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT PID, MENU, Handler,PageLangID, ParentID,IssueID, CatID,MenuPosition FROM MENUTABLE ";

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
    DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
    DataRow[] parentMenus = table.Select("ParentId = 0");
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
         string unorderedList = GenerateUL(parentMenus, table, sb);
    }

    private string GenerateUL(DataRow[] menu, DataTable table, StringBuilder sb)
    {
    sb.AppendLine("<ul>");

    try
    {

        if (menu.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in menu)
            {
                ctr = ctr + 1;
                string handler = dr["Handler"].ToString();
                string menuText = dr["MENU"].ToString();
                string line = String.Format(@"<li><a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>", handler, menuText);
                sb.Append(line);

                string pid = dr["PID"].ToString();

                DataRow[] subMenu = table.Select(String.Format("ParentId = {0}", pid));
                if (subMenu.Length > 0)
                {
                    var subMenuBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append(GenerateUL(subMenu, table, subMenuBuilder));
                }
                sb.Append("</li>");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    sb.Append("</ul>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Update: When i change my query which get me result below then it works fine, but it would be good to make it work on actual data which is shown first in the question.

```
PID         MENU                 Handler                  PageLangID  ParentID    IssueID     CatID       MenuPosition
----------- -------------------- ------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
1           Home                 Default.aspx             1           0           1           1           10
2           About Us             Page.aspx                1           0           1           1           20
3           News                 News.aspx                1           0           1           1           30
5           Articles             Articles.aspx            1           0           1           1           20
6           Categories           Category.aspx    1           0           1           1           25
```

Comment: This is already asked,you can see this on below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485434/logic-for-displaying-infinite-category-tree-in-nested-uls-from-self-join-table

Comment: @Mayur, Looks like a good solution but i am not able to understand it as it using LINQ and `DataClasses1DataContext` . I need it for asp.net-webform using c#

Comment: remove Dataclass1datacontext and context and instead of context you can use myDataTable.Select("ParentID == 0") and instead of IQueryable<Menu> menus you can use var menus.

Comment: @Mayur, Appreciate your help i have updated question but it doesn't work i am doing something wrong in the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've created a slightly simpler table structure on my side as we only need the following columns for the sake of example :

1. PID
2. MENU
3. Handler
4. ParentID

**Sample data:**

As you can see from this example we have a 3 way deep hierarchy for Product and the rest of the items have no children.

[image]

**Code behind:**

The code below does the following:

1. First gets all items with no parents and starts looping through them
2. Checks whether an item is a parent to any node and gets its children recursively.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select("SELECT * FROM Menu");
       DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
       DataRow[] parentMenus = table.Select("ParentId = 0");

       var sb = new StringBuilder();
       string unorderedList = GenerateUL(parentMenus, table,sb);
       Response.Write(unorderedList);
   }

   private string GenerateUL(DataRow[] menu,DataTable table,StringBuilder sb)
   {
       sb.AppendLine("<ul>");

       if (menu.Length > 0)
       {
           foreach (DataRow dr in menu)
           {
               string handler = dr["Handler"].ToString();
               string menuText = dr["MENU"].ToString();
               string line = String.Format(@"<li><a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>",handler,menuText);
               sb.Append(line);

               string pid = dr["PID"].ToString();

               DataRow[]subMenu = table.Select(String.Format("ParentId = {0}", pid));
               if (subMenu.Length > 0)
               {
                   var subMenuBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                   sb.Append(GenerateUL(subMenu, table, subMenuBuilder));
               }
               sb.Append("</li>");
           }
       }

       sb.Append("</ul>");
       return sb.ToString();
   }
   ```

**End result:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the code constructs the menu based on ParentID's and for ID=6 the ParentID also happens to be 6. So 6 calls 6 and we have an endless loop,great.

Now that we know what the issue is, we can put in a simple check to construct sub menus recursively only if `ParentId != PID` , here's the updated code:

```
private string GenerateUL(DataRow[] menu, DataTable table, StringBuilder sb)
{
    sb.AppendLine("<ul>");

    if (menu.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in menu)
        {
            string handler = dr["Handler"].ToString();
            string menuText = dr["MENU"].ToString();
            string line = String.Format(@"<li><a href=""{0}"">{1}</a>", handler, menuText);
            sb.Append(line);

            string pid = dr["PID"].ToString();
            string parentId = dr["ParentId"].ToString();

            DataRow[] subMenu = table.Select(String.Format("ParentId = {0}", pid));
            if (subMenu.Length > 0 && !pid.Equals(parentId))
            {
                var subMenuBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(GenerateUL(subMenu, table, subMenuBuilder));
            }
            sb.Append("</li>");
        }
    }
    sb.Append("</ul>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I think the important thing here is to actually understand how this code works by stepping through it in the debugger, that way you'll be able to change if any other issues come up.

Comment: Thanks for your solution which seems to be a working one but it is generating `StackOverFlowException` in my case after implementing your solution. I noticed that i goes into loop endlessly which i was debugging it  for some reason, I have actually 23 rows in my table i thought it might loop 23 time but it loops more that that & generates error for where pid=6, I will update my question & screen shots of error for reference. ANyway i appreciate your solution & hope you can solve this misty for me

Comment: I've made an update.Give it a try and let me know whether it solves your problem!Please mark as answered if my post helped you

Comment: @Dani, Thanks it works now with the duplicate PID also as required. Appreciate you help. I am sure this code will help lot of people as i could not find similar code which works with datatable. Great Solution.